# Pass c++ objects in Objective c wrapper

Tags: c++, objective-c

From what I understand you cannot pass c++ objects directly in objectiveC...I think. Instead you have to pass a pointer. Do you have to pass a void pointer and cast it?

For example if I have two C++ objects **b2World**, and **b2Body**.
If I then create two objective c wrappers **World**, **Body** do I then pass **b2Body** to **World** with a void pointer and cast it inside **World**?

Comment: If you want to use C++ objects, you should convert your code to Objective-C++.

Comment: Obviously, but you still need to be able make methods that can return a c++ object. You can't do that in a header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that I was originally correct. You can pass c++ objects around through void pointers and then cast them.